# Merge array inside different collections inside same array

Tags: arrays, laravel, collections

I am getting an array with collections and inside those collections there are arrays again. what i want to do is merge the collections to have just one collection with all the arrays of the multiple collection.

```
Collection {#1592 ▼
  #items: array:4 [▼
    0 => Collection {#1595 ▼
      #items: array:2 [▶]
    }
    1 => Collection {#1589 ▶}
    2 => Collection {#1585 ▼
      #items: array:2 [▶]
    }
    3 => Collection {#1579 ▼
      #items: array:2 [▶]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [flatten()](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#method-flatten) method of collections:

ie)

```
$a = collect(['a', 'b', 'c']);
$d = collect(['d', 'e', 'f']);
$g = collect(['g', 'h', 'i']);

$c = collect([$a, $d, $g]);

$c->flatten();
```

Will output:

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection {#3124
    all: [
        "a",
        "b",
        "c",
        "d",
        "e",
        "f",
        "g",
        "h",
        "i",
    ],
}
```